# Eclipse PDE headless builds modifies source dirs and MANIFEST.MF

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde, headless

## The problem

From a number of OSGi bundles, I am creating a p2 update site using the PDE headless feature build. I don't want to copy the entire source tree (if it can be avoided) so I point the `buildDirectory` property to the location of my sources.

The general problem I encounter is that the PDE build sprinkles build artifacts all over the source directory (and not like all other decent build tools where the build artifacts are stored to a separate location like e.g. Maven's `target` folder). I can live with this but more annoying is that the PDE build modifies the `MANIFEST.MF` file of each compiled bundle.

The only real change to the `MANIFEST.MF` file is that

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
```

is rewritten to

```
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.<yyyyMMddhhmm>
```

Apart from that, the entire file is reformatted. Of course it is correct to rewrite the file to what should end up in the assembled jars but the modified manifest should IMHO *not* overwrite the source manifest.

## A possible solution?

Does anybody know if there is a way to tell PDE headless build to send all build artifacts to a location separate from the source files?

## The nitty gritty details...

Please find below the details about my build.

### How I call PDE headless

This is the command I use to call PDE headless build:

```
java \
  -jar \
  <prefix>/eclipse/3.8.1/SDK/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar \
  -application \
  org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner \
  -buildfile \
  <prefix>/eclipse/3.8.1/SDK/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.1.v20120725-202643/scripts/build.xml \
  -data \
  <prefix>/target/pde_workspace \
  -Dbuilder=<prefix>/eclipse/3.8.1/SDK/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.8.1.v20120725-202643/templates/headless-build \
  -DtopLevelElementId=org.example.myproject.feature \
  -DtopLevelElementType=feature \
  -DbuildDirectory=<prefix>/source \
  -DbaseLocation=<prefix>/targetPlatform \
  -DjavacSource=1.7 \
  -DjavacTarget=1.7 \
  -DcompilerArg=-g \
  -DbuildLabel=output \
  -DarchivePrefix=org.example.myproject \
  -DbuildId=org.example.myproject.feature \
  -DarchivesFormat=*,*,* - folder \
  -Dp2.gathering=true \
  -Dp2.build.repo=<prefix>/target/update-site \
  -DskipMirroring=true \
  -DcollectingFolder=<prefix>/target/tmp
```

My hope was that adding `-DcollectingFolder` would redirect all build artifacts to this folder, but it is left empty.

### PDE headless documentation

The documentation for PDE headless builds is comprehensive yet somewhat imprecise. For example, for one of its many options it says:

> buildType: Type of build, normally something like I, N, M, etc.

The documentation I have been able to find is this:

- http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpde_builder_config.htm

Does anyone know of other documentation of the PDE headless builds?

Comment: The build does a lot of messing around in the build directory so it is normal to create this from scratch copying in all the source.

Comment: @greg-449 I know, and this is what we normally do, but it is really silly to copy over a _really_ large source dir (> 300 bundles) every time you build.

Comment: Sorry but I really think that is what has to be done. I think the expectation is that this is used by an automated build which would be creating the directory by checking code out from your source control system.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the properties `buildTempFolder` and `feature.temp.folder`.  I don't believe that these properties are documented anywhere.

If you are familiar with ant, the way to discover this would be to look at the build.xml file that gets generated for a plugin.  In the `<init>` target, if **buildTempFolder** is set, then the build will end up setting something like

> build.result.folder=${buildTempFolder}/plugins/org.example.plugin_1.2.3.201411110853`

If *buildTempFolder* is not set, then the default value is *${basedir}*, which is the root folder of the plugin.

This *build.result.folder* will be the destination for most of the compiled .class files (see the `<@dot>` target), and the manifest will be copied there before it is modified (see the `<publish.bin.parts>` target.  If you use customBuildCallbacks, then everything will be staged here before calling your custom callbacks.

The **feature.temp.folder** is similar to the *buildTempFolder* but affects features instead of plugins.